# Echoing content sometimes takes a very long time

Tags: php, performance

I have a script that builds my webpage in one string ($content) and then echo it to the user.

My script looks like this:

```
$time1= microtime(true);
$content = create_content();
$content_time=(microtime(true)-$time1)

$time = microtime(true);
echo $content;
$echo_time = (microtime(true)-$time);
```

Now $content_time is always well under 0.5s so thats no problem. However a few times a day the $echo_time is well above one second and can even go up to 15 seconds. The content isn't really big, about 10-20kb and the times at which this happens are completly random, so it's not on the busy times and even happen in the middle of the night.

Anybody have any idea what that can be?

EDIT
The site is hosted on a (remote) dedicated server and only host this site. There is a database involved but like I say the $content_time is well under 1 second, so what this function does can not be the delay.

When the time of my site is above a certain value (lets say 5s) I log this. Even Googlebots seems to have these issues sometimes so I don't think they use a dial-up connection :)

Comment: I think that nobody can answer it, there is a lot of parts of which the poblem can be caused. First of all - local machine, or remote server, VPS or dedicated or just hosting. Need details...

Comment: there might be some load in the server at the time...

Comment: as @devdRew your going to need to provide more details like some code that is creating the content. is there a database, is this on a web server or local machine, etc.

Comment: May be your server has very very high ping. Or You're using dial up (then how could you post on SO)?

Comment: I added some more info in the question

Comment: Although everything is possible, it seems unlikely since it also happens at times when there are hardly visitors (like in the middle of the night). I also checked that at those times no cronjobs where running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's narrow the issue down and factor out some things...

In the question you indicate you're echoing out 10-15kb.   That's a significant amount no matter how it's buffered to output--remember php is single thread, once you flush your buffer you got to wait for all the output to happen via the shell or HTTP before the script continues.  It will eventually have to flush the internal buffer before continuing the echo.  To get good time without the flushing overhead of echo

Try replacing the

```
$time = microtime(true);
echo $content;
$echo_time = (microtime(true)-$time);
```

With

```
ob_start();
$time = microtime(true);
echo $content;
$echo_time = (microtime(true)-$time);
ob_clean();
```

This will echo to a buffer, but not actually spit it out via HTTP or whatever.  That should give you the 'real' time of the echo command without any concern sending out what's in the buffer.

If echo_time shrinks down, you have a transport issue to address as best you can with buffering.

If echo_time is still to large, you'll need to start digging into the PHP C code.

Either way you're a lot closer to finding your issue and a solution

Comment: @Nin Were you able to try this to narrow your issue down?

Comment: No I still haven't managed to figure out why this is happening. Problem is that I can't reproduce. I'll accept your answer though.

Answer (score 5):

From http://wonko.com/post/seeing_poor_performance_using_phps_echo_statement_heres_why

[This old bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18029) may shed some light. In short, using echo to send large strings to the browser results in horrid performance due to the way [Nagle’s Algorithm](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/sDefinition/0,,sid7_gci754347,00.html) causes data to be buffered for transmission over TCP/IP.

The solution? A simple three-line function that splits large strings into smaller chunks before echoing them:

```
function echobig($string, $bufferSize = 8192) { 
    $splitString = str_split($string, $bufferSize);

    foreach($splitString as $chunk) { echo $chunk; }
}
```

Play around with the buffer size and see what works best for you. I found that 8192, apart from being a nice round number, seemed to be a good size. Certain other values work too, but I wasn’t able to discern a pattern after several minutes of tinkering and there’s obviously some math at work that I have no desire to try to figure out.

By the way, the performance hit also happens when using PHP’s output control functions (ob_start() and friends)

Following the OPs comment that he's tried this I also found the following on PHP.net suggesting that str_split can also be a waste of resources and the echobig function can be optimised further by using the following code:

```
function echobig($string, $bufferSize = 8192) {
  // suggest doing a test for Integer & positive bufferSize
  for ($chars=strlen($string)-1,$start=0;$start <= $chars;$start += $bufferSize) {
    echo substr($string,$start,$buffer_size);
  }
}
```

Have you tried running your script using the CLI rather than through Apache?

Comment: I already tried that but it doens't help. I still see it perform very badly (2+sec).

Comment: Have you fiddled around with the buffer size as suggested in the article?

Comment: No I haven't fiddled around with the buffersize, first because I can't reproduce this myself, I can only see it in my logs. But mainly because changeing it to this (from the normal echo $content) had no effect, so I don't really think changing the value will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this better using output buffers. On a basic level, you use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to begin writing to an output buffer, and then `ob_end_flush()` to push it to the client. Here is what php.net has to say about `ob_start()`:

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>   The contents of this internal buffer may be copied into a string variable using `ob_get_contents()`. To output what is stored in the internal buffer, use `ob_end_flush()`.

Comment: This is mainly usefull when you make multiple echo statements, but in this case there is only 1 echo, so the buffering is done in the script already.

Comment: True, but buffers also allow compression which can significantly reduce bandwidth. You can also reuse a buffer or cache it. It really comes down to what OP needs to accomplish.

Comment: But that can't be the difference between 0.0007s (normal) and 13s (peak)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the past very similar to yours. I found that this problem can be caused by slow clients. If client fetched half of the page and then hangs, php will wait until client is ready and then sends rest of the content. So it could be not problem on your side.

### Update:

You can try following scripts on your server to check this. This script put on your server and call it echo.php:

```
<?php
$time_start = time();
echo str_repeat("a", 200000);
echo "\nThis script took: " . (time() - $time_start) . " sec";
```

Then fetch it with this script (change example.com to your domain):

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET /echo.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 5000);
        sleep(1);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I've got `echo.php` running 27 seconds. When I remove line `sleep(1)`, `echo.php` takes only 2 seconds to run.

Comment: I thought about that as well (and might be the only thing possible) but I do see the Google bot suffer from the same thing and I think they have fast connections. But maybe they have some hickups as well....

Answer (score 0):

As it is not possible to tell you the reason without knowing the body of your create_content() function I suggest you to add more "time logging" functions directly inside this function. Making the included code fewer and fewer you will finally find the line that is causing the lag.
Knowing the specific line will help you to understand the problem (database, machine load, connection problems to external services, ...).

Comment: The create_content() function performs well under 0.5s so that function is not the problem. Its the `$echo_time` that is the problem. The create_content() function is only in the sample code to show that $content is created somewhere and that that performs well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any while() or for() loops in your script? If so, you should check if these values aren't conflicting with anything, Occasionally I forgot about these myself and my script would also run for about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that the act of accessing that large of a string takes up a decent amount of memory over multiple uses. Because PHP is garbage collected, memory is taken up until the garbage collecter is ran, then it's freed. **My guess is that multiple requests to store content in a string variable is causing the rapid filling up of volatile memory (RAM)**. Then a few times a day you start hitting the limit causing the slower load times. Garbage collecter hits, and everything is back to normal.

Comment: The server has 16GB of ram with almost always 8GB free (inactive). Besides that, the issue is not generating the string, its only the echoing of it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is dedicated server - please login to console and see which process uses a lot of cpu time when you generating content. Its very hard to tell, when we cant see code. Maybe you just need some indexes in database, or maybe you should remove some indexes.

You can also check httpd and mysqld log files.